# Keyboard shortcut to extend to 2nd monitor in vmplayer?

Tags: multiple-monitors, keyboard-shortcuts, vmware-player

I am using Vmware player and my host OS is Windows 8 (guest OS is Lubuntu 14.04). I removed the top bar of my VMplayer because I found it annoying. I did this by going into

```
C:\Users\{your_username}\AppData\Roaming\VMware\preferences.ini
```

and then adding

```
pref.vmplayer.fullscreen.nobar = 1
```

at the end of the file. The issue is, now when I open up VMplayer and run my guest OS, I go into full screen mode with

<kbd>Cntrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd>

but I can't cycle through multiple monitors since my top bar is not there. Any idea what the keyboard shortcut is to cycle through multiple monitors using VMplayer?

Comment: So are you on full screen mode all the time when you open VM player?

Comment: @Prasanna I can go into small screen mode by hitting "Cntrl + Alt + Enter". When VMplayer is in small screen mode, there is a "Full screen" button and a "Unity" button (this "Unity" button turns into the "Cycle through multiple desktops" button after I go into full screen mode but since I disabled the top bar, I can't see the "Cycle through multiple desktops" button once I am in full screen).

Answer (score 0):

Searching for a solution I found this topic and I want to share a work around that I found.

Instead of removing the command bar, consider setting the size of the bar to 0. By this, the top bar can still be accessed but is not visible anymore.

```
pref.vmplayer.fullscreen.autohideSize = "0"
```